# Is it possible to peform thermodynamic work by harvesting entanglement from the vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, energy-conservation, entropy, quantum-entanglement, vacuum

I have already asked two questions on this topic:

[1. What happens to the vacuum when entanglement is harvested? [closed]](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649558/)
and

[2. Does entanglement harvesting require cooling the environment to sufficiently low temperatures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/649017/)

I wonder whether it is at least in theory possible to harvest the entanglement from the vacuum and then use it to perform thermodynamic work, because I read in papers that quantum coherence can be used to perform work [1,2,3]. I have done some research into this topic, however I found that it requires energy to harvest entanglement [4,5]. (The two papers show different costs - not sure about that). The key question is does it require more or less energy to harvest entanglement than can be gained. As expected The harvested entanglement falls off with the distance [6]. However for the application of thermodynamic work gain it is not required to maintain entanglement over large distance.
All in all this idea seems too obvious and it is unlikely that people haven't thought about this yet. So I am guessing there are some complications with this idea. Anyway, I hope someone can clarify my doubt.

Papers on thermodynamic work gain from entanglement
[1] https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.1078955
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6872
[3] https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.1630

Papers on entanglement extraction cost
[4] https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2019-07-15-165
[5] https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06153-w

Harvested entanglement falls off with distance
[6] https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0212044

Comment: In general please do not link directly to documents (e.g. pdfs).  On this site please link to the abstract page for the document if one is available.

Comment: @StephenG Sorry about that, I corrected it just now.