# Overview of quantum energy teleportation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, quantum-teleportation

I'm looking for a research-level review of the concept of quantum energy teleportation.

I did find [http://www.tuhep.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/~hotta/extended-version-qet-review.pdf](http://www.tuhep.phys.tohoku.ac.jp/%7Ehotta/extended-version-qet-review.pdf), but it is more than 10 years old. Is there anything more recent, or is the above reference still useful?

Comment: related on qc.SE: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/30403/55

Comment: Until very recently QET was very niche, now there are some simulations. I doubt that there is any review aside from Hotta's yet.

Comment: Check this presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-mStC-E1l0&ab_channel=InstituteforQuantumComputing